# How could I make new empty and valid datadir for MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, data-loss, mariadb

I forgot root's password. After I reset it, mysql utility allowed me to login with any password. I bluntly deleted datadir(/var/
lib/mysql entirely).
Now have a problem of making new valid datadir.

Yes, I did good search but have not found a solution yet.

**Could you show a method to do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command `mysql_install_db`

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db/